# How can I find the day of the year, year, month and day for now in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an application that requires me to get the following:

```
    int doy // Day of the year
    int yr  // Two digit year
    int mon // Two digit month (zero on left for small numbers)
    int day // Two digit day   (zero on left for small numbers)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get these numbers using C#?

Comment: Official MS Docs: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: @Alan2 What do you mean with *"zero on left for small numbers"*? `int`s are numbers, they don't have leading zeros.

Comment: @Alan2 did you check the class's documentation? It's all there. So is the documentation on formatting

Comment: @Neo the value returned by [DateTime.DayOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the numbers with 0 padded on left, you will have to use string format.

```
        int doy = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;// Day of the year
        string yr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");// Two digit year
        string mon = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("d2"); // Two digit month (zero on left for small numbers)
        string day = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("d2"); // Two digit day   (zero on left for small numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(doy);
    Console.WriteLine(yr);
    Console.WriteLine(mon);
    Console.WriteLine(day);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.DateTime moment = new System.DateTime.Now;

int year = moment.Year;
int month = moment.Month;
int day = moment.Day;
int hour = moment.Hour;
int minute = moment.Minute;
int second = moment.Second;
int millisecond = moment.Millisecond;
```

Have a look here: [MSDN Documentation - DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks that looks good

Comment: @Anne3 read the docs. It's all there. Numbers DON'T have padding. Strings do. Check the docs for `ToString()` and datetime formatting

Comment: @Anne3 Are you hijacking Alan2's question or do you have two accounts?

Answer (score 3):

like this

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear); // day of year
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Month); // month of year 
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Year); // year
```

Calculate week of year based on culture if the week start on Monday because other culture does not start on Monday like Arabic

```
int day = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
var week = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

easy way to get week number is

```
  Console.WriteLine( System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Comment: I highly disagree with your way of calculating the "week of year". That's usually done via the Calender and is determined differently depending on the culture (specifically the CalendarWeekRule ) - see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Saif,  I like your answer but agree with Manfred.  Maybe the calculation of week is something I need to do differently.

Comment: @Alan2 The correct way is linked in my comment - it's really easy when you know what you are doing.

Comment: I agree, but see the update answer

Comment: @Saif No need for complicated calculations

Comment: Updated.. I have included both options